# docker postgresql access from other container

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a docker-compose file which is globally like this.

```
version '2'

services:
  app:
    image: myimage
    ports:
      - "80:80"
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_adress: 192.168.22.22

  db:
    image: postgres:9.5
    ports: 
      - "6432:5432"
    networks:
      mynet:
        ipv4_adress: 192.168.22.23

...


networks:
  mynet:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
      - subnet: 192.168.22.0/24
```

I want to put my postgresql and application in subnetworks to avoid the ports to be exposed outside my computer/server.

From within the app container, I can't connect to 192.168.22.23, I installed net-tools to use ifconfig/netstat, and it doesn't seem the containers are able to communicate.

I assume I have this problem because I'm using subnetworks with static ipv4 adresses.

I can access both static IPs from the host (connect to postgres and access the application)

Do you have any piece of advice, the goal is to access the ports of another container to communicate with him, without removing the use of static ips (on app at least). Here, to connect to postgresql from the app container.

Comment: you do not set your network `mynet` in networks section

Comment: I don't have the dockerfile with me right now, was a typo. thanks

Comment: Delete all of this `networks:` manual configuration.  If you don’t set `ports:` then the containers still won’t be reachable from off-host.  Use the service block names like `db` as host names to communicated between containers.  Never think about the container-internal IP addresses.

Comment: @DavidMaze forgot to rewrite the ports rules on 'db' and 'app'. How am I supposed to write my nginx `proxy_pass` rule from host if I don't use static ips to identify my containers ?

Comment: With the host’s IP address and `ports:`.  On many platforms (including Docker for Mac and anything that uses Docker Toolbox) you cannot use the container-internal IP address at all.  You can specify `ports: [‘127.0.0.1:8080:8080’]` to make something reachable from processes on the host, but not off-host.

Comment: @DavidMaze I didn't know about that ports syntax. Thanks, will try this evening. You can post this as an answer and I'll validate it when I will see it works fine ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `docker run -p` option and Docker Compose `ports:` option take a bind address as an optional parameter.  You can use this to make a service accessible from the same host, but not from other hosts:

```
services:
  db:
    ports:
      - '127.0.0.1:6432:5432'
```

(The other good use of this setting is if you have a gateway machine with both a public and private network interface, and you want a service to only be accessible from the private network.)

Once you have this, you can dispense with all of the manual `networks:` setup.  Non-Docker services on the same host can reach the service via the special host name `localhost` and the published port number.  Docker services can use inter-container networking; within the same `docker-compose.yml` file you can use the service name as a host name, and the internal port number.

```
host$ PGHOST=localhost PGPORT=6432 psql
```

```
services:
  app:
    environment:
      - PGHOST=db
      - PGPORT=5432
```

You should remove all of the manual `networks:` setup, and in general try not to think about the Docker-internal IP addresses at all.  If your Docker is Docker for Mac or Docker Toolbox, you cannot reach the internal IP addresses at all.  In a multi-host environment they will be similarly unreachable from hosts other than where the container itself is running.

Comment: using ports with `127.0.0.1:portHost:portContainer` works perfectly, removed all my networks. thanks !